# Microsoft speech recognition PhraseLIst undefined,what is the issue?

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

currently developing an app with Microsoft speech Rec and its going well except when attempting to user the PhraseListGrammar object it keeps retruning undefined, what is the issue?

```
recognizer = new SpeechSDK.SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);
recognizer.BabbleTimeout = 0.75;
var phraseListGrammar = 
**SpeechSDK.PhraseListGrammar.fromRecognizer(recognizer);**
```

the last line give me the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'fromRecognizer' of undefined
```

Why can I not create the PhraseListGrammar object so i can give it a list of poossible words to recognize. this can dramatically increase the effectiveness of my app and decrease the error rate so someone please help. Thank you.

Comment: This thing is pretty recent, what is yoru SDK version?

Comment: yep, that was the issue, thank you. I will mark this as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed to update my sdk version.